# perl script to parse file help needed

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl.
I have a file which i need to parse using perl script.

The format of the file is as below:

```
05\/26\/2013 06:09:47 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:47 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolched@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:48 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash2s@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:48 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolchedssd@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:49 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.43 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:49 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=kjsdsdjhjsh@abc.com
```

From the file i want to get something like these:

```
05/26/2013 06:09:49  and uid=radash@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
```

from each line.

I've tried split(), but i'm not able to get it properly.

Please help

Comment: Why would split not work?

Comment: If split won't work try [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) for fun then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple script with split

```
my $IP_FILE=$ARGV[0];
open(IP_FILE,$IP_FILE) || die "Unable to open file...";
while(<IP_FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my @vals = split("-");
    $vals[0] =~ s/\\//g;
    $vals[7] =~ s/\\//g;
    printf("%s %s\n",$vals[0],$vals[7]);
}
close(IP_FILE);
```

Comment: Btw can you please recommend any book or links to quickly learn perl? also i would like to learn using ldap with perl

Comment: @david The Perl website has excellent documentation and a brief introductory tutorial.

Comment: @Raghuram I have one problem now.

There are some lines like:

5\/26\/2013 06:09:47 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=rada-sh@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:47 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolched@abc.com

Due to this:  uid=rada-sh    , split is not working properly, can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new pattern in the file....as i am not able to make out whats the difference between old and new pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ape '$_ = "$F[0] $F[1]  and $F[14]\n"; s|\\||g;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #open file 
 open(FILE, "FILENAME.txt")  || die "Can't open file";

 # read file into an array 
 @data = <FILE>;
 close(FILE);
 foreach $line(@data) {

 @output = split / /, $line;
 $output[0] =~ s/\\//g;
 print "$output[0] $output[1] and $output[16]\n";
 }
```

or you can push it to use later.

```
 #open file 
 open(FILE, "FILENAME.txt")  || die "Can't open file";

 # read file into an array 
 @data = <FILE>;
 close(FILE);
 foreach $line(@data) {

 @output = split / /, $line;
 $output[0] =~ s/\\//g;
 push @result, "$output[0] $output[1] and $output[16]\n";
 }
 print @result;
```

Not very clean code, because if the file's data ever moves to other locations within the file, it will give incorrect results, but this works and you'll get the idea of how the split works.

As for your question on links. Here is a good beginners eBook.

```
  http://bookboon.com/en/perl-for-beginners-ebook
```

Comment: @david here is a good book to start with. it is free! http://bookboon.com/en/perl-for-beginners-ebook

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '$a="@F[0,1]";$a=~s/[\\\/]//g;$F[14]=~s/\\//g;print "$a and $F[14]"' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the delimiter, `-` you can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) to parse it. It is a core module in Perl 5. I supply the regex `\s*-\s*` to strip the whitespace around the dashes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = quotewords('\s*-\s*', 0, $_);
    say join " ", @data[0, 6];
}


__DATA__
05\/26\/2013 06:09:47 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:47 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolched@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:48 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash2s@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:48 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolchedssd@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:49 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.43 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:49 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=kjsdsdjhjsh@abc.com
```

**Output:**

```
05/26/2013 06:09:47 -0700 uid=radash@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
05/26/2013 06:09:48 -0700 uid=radash2s@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
05/26/2013 06:09:49 -0700 uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
```